# Almost sure strong convergence of the empirical distribution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, empirical-processes

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed real-valued random variables, each defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and with distribution $Q(\cdot)=P(X_i \in \cdot)$. For every measurable set $A$ in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, let 
$$Q_n(A)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nI\{X_i\in A\}.$$
From the Strong Law of Large Numbers it follows that 
$$P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} Q_n(A) = Q(A) \right)=1\textrm{ for every  $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.}$$
However, the Strong Law of Large Numbers alone is not sufficient to obtain the following stronger result:
$$P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} Q_n(A) = Q(A) \textrm{ for every 
set $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.}\right)=1,$$
which amount to the [strong convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Strong_convergence_of_measures) of the empirical distribution  $Q_n(\cdot)$ to the law $Q(\cdot)$ over $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

**Question**: Under what conditions does the empirical distribution $Q_n(\cdot)$ converge strongly to $Q(\cdot)$ over $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$? Can it converge strongly at least over some uncountable subset $S\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: It can be shown that if the set of all possible values of $X$ is finite or countably infinite then we get (simultaneous and strong) convergence over _all_ sets $A$ in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. This is not trivial in the case when $X$ can take countably many values since the set of all subsets of those values  is in fact uncountably infinite.

Comment: @ a . arfe : Do you have a counter-example to the claim $$P\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n(A) = P[X\in A] \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right]=1$$?

Comment: So far I could not think of a counterexample. Instead I found another large class $S$ that would satisfy the thesis: since $Q_n$ converges weakly almost surely, by the [Portmanteau theorem]{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures} the thesis holds if $S$ is the set of all $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $Q(\partial A)=0$, where $\partial A$ is the boundary of $A$.

Comment: I will look at the above link you give.  I have modified my answer to show that discrete random variables are the _only_ ones for which the convergence holds for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I'm still a little lost, so I'll try to make my argument more explicit. By the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, with probability 1 it is $Q_n((-\infty,x])\rightarrow F(x):=Q((-\infty,x])$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This implies that, with probability 1, $Q_n$ converges weakly to $Q$, since the previous convergence is true for all continuity points of $F(x)$. The rest follows by the equivalence of weak convergence and set-wise convergence over $Q$-continuity sets, as per the Portmanteau theorem. What is wrong with this argument?

Comment: It is a standard result, stated for example in the Wikipedia page that I already linked.

Comment: I see.  You are fixing $\omega$ and defining the measure as given by the sample path. This seems correct.  It does not contradict my result below (as I suggested in the above comment) because, although my collection of sets  $\mathcal{J}$ contains only sets $J$ that are finite or countably infinite, that does not mean the boundary of such sets $J$ is equal to $J$ (or has measure 0) because the boundary of a countably infinite set can be larger than the set (such as when that set is dense, like the boundary of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have deleted my comment after your Portmanteau observation, the gist of which was to ask which bullet points you were usign and to suggest that my sets $J$ in $\mathcal{J}$ have measure zero boundary, which is not teh case.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer shows that all random variables  yield  simultaneous convergence over sets  $(-\infty, x]$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. **However, we get simultaneous convergence over all sets in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if the random variable is discrete.**

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability triple and let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be i.i.d. random variables.  Define $X=X_1$.

1) Suppose $X$ has any CDF $F_X(x)$. The Glivenko-Cantelli theorem implies that 
$$ P\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Q_n((-\infty, x])=F_X(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\right]=1$$
This positively answers the question "Can it converge strongly at least over some uncountable subset $S \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?"

2) Suppose $X$ takes values in a finite or countably infinite set $\mathcal{X}$.   We want to show
$$ P\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n(A)= P[X\in A] \quad \forall A \in  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right] = 1$$
It suffices to show 
$$ P\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Q_n(V) = P[X \in V] \quad \forall V \subseteq \mathcal{X}\right]=1$$

The law of large numbers implies that for any element $x \in \mathcal{X}$ we get: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Q_n(\{x\}) = P[X=x] \quad \mbox{with prob 1}$$
Define the event
$$ B = \cap_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Q_n(\{x\})= P[X=x]\right\}$$ 
Since $\mathcal{X}$ is at most a countably infinite set we get $P[B]=1$. It suffices to show
$$ B\subseteq \left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Q_n(V)= P[X \in V] \quad \forall V \subseteq \mathcal{X}\right\}$$
(In fact, the above inclusion will imply that $B$ is equal to the set on the right-hand-side, since the opposite inclusion clearly holds.) Suppose $B$ holds true.  Fix $V \subseteq \mathcal{X}$. We get
$$ Q_n(V) = \sum_{x \in V} Q_n(\{x\})$$
Now, because $B$ holds true, we know $Q_n(\{x\})$ values are nonnegative and satisfy 
$Q_n(\{x\}) \rightarrow P[X=x]$ for all $x \in V$.   Also we get $Q_n(V)\leq 1$ for all $n$. So we can dominate the sum by 1 and we get by Lebesgue dominated convergence (applied deterministically to the summation via the counting measure): 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n(V) = \sum_{x \in V} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n(\{x\}) = \sum_{x \in V} P[X=x] = P[X \in V]$$ $\Box$

3) This section shows that simultaneous convergence for all sets in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (surely) fails if $X$ is *not* a discrete random variable.

#### Claim:

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the set of all points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $P[X=x]>0$ and suppose $P[X \in \mathcal{X}]<1$. Define the set 
$$ B = \left\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n(A) = P[X\in A] \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right\}$$
Then $B$ is the empty set and so $P[B]=0$.

#### Proof:

We know $\mathcal{X}$ is either finite or countably infinite and so $\mathcal{X} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. By definition of $\mathcal{X}$ we know that $P[X =v]=0$ for all $v \in \mathcal{X}^c$. Also,
$$P[X \in \mathcal{X}^c] =1-P[X\in \mathcal{X}]>0$$
Define $\theta = P[X \in \mathcal{X}^c]$ (so $\theta >0$).

Define $\mathcal{J}$ as the collection of all sets of the type $\mathcal{X} \cup C$ where $C$ is a finite or countably infinite subset of $\mathcal{X}^c$.  Note that every set $J \in \mathcal{J}$ is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Letting $J=\mathcal{X} \cup C$ be a particular set in $\mathcal{J}$, we have
\begin{align}
P[X \in J] &= P[X \in \mathcal{X} \cup C] \\
&= P[X \in \mathcal{X}] + P[X \in C] \\
&= (1-\theta) + \sum_{v \in C}\underbrace{P[X=v]}_{0}\\
&=1-\theta \\
&<1
\end{align}

Now, for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and all $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ define: 
$$Q_n^{\omega}(A) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I\{X_i(\omega) \in A\}$$
For a given outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ we can define the set $D(\omega)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ by: 
$$ D(\omega)= \mathcal{X} \cup \{x \in \mathcal{X}^c: x = X_n(\omega) \quad \mbox{for some $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$}\}$$
Then $D(\omega)$ is just the union of $\mathcal{X}$ with a finite or countably infinite number of elements of $\mathcal{X}^c$.  Thus,
$$D(\omega)  \in \mathcal{J} \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega$$
It is clear by the definition of $D(\omega)$ that 
$$ I\{X_n(\omega) \in D(\omega)\} = 1 \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega, n \in \{1, 2, ,3 ...\}$$
and so 
$$ Q_n^{\omega}(D(\omega)) = 1 \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega, n \in \{1, 2, ,3 ...\}$$
Thus
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n^{\omega}(D(\omega)) = 1 \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega$$
Hence
$$ \left\{\omega \in \Omega : \cap_{J \in \mathcal{J}} \left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n^{\omega}(J) = \underbrace{P[X \in J]}_{1-\theta}\right\}\right\} =\phi $$
where $\phi$ is the empty set.  This is because the above intersection over all sets in $\mathcal{J}$ includes the set $D(\omega)$, for which we know the limit is $1$ (not $1-\theta$).  Since all sets in $\mathcal{J}$ are in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ it holds that
$$ \left\{\omega \in \Omega : \cap_{A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})} \left\{  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n^{\omega}(A)= P[X\in A]\right\}\right\} = \phi$$ $\Box$